# Null Pointer Exception and scope in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to learn object oriented programming in the context of Java. I am writing a fairly simple code, but am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Advisor_score.Rating.Score(Rating.java:12)
at Advisor_score.Rating.main(Rating.java:25)
```

Here is my code:

```
package Advisor_score;
public class Rating {
    double [] Ratings;
    double sum;
    double raw_advisor;
    double advisor_score;
    public Rating (double [] x){
        double [] Ratings = x;
    }

    public double Score(){
        for(int i=2;i<Ratings.length;i++){
            sum+=Ratings[i];
        }
        raw_advisor=((sum-(3*(Ratings.length-2)))/4);
        advisor_score= 2.5+(2.5*(1-Math.pow(Math.E, -.5*raw_advisor)));
        return advisor_score;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(advisor_score);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        double p1_1[] = {101,1,1,1.5,.5};
        Rating d = new Rating(p1_1);
        d.Score();
        d.print();
    }
}
```

I have been looking at this for hours and cannot figure out the problem with the code. I am new to programming can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Java" isn't an acronym, so please don't write it in capital letters.

Comment: Spencer, are you learning Java at a university (or college)? If so, is that university misspelling "Java" as "JAVA"? I only ask because I'm trying to figure out where the misspelling originates from. :)

Comment: Capitalize the first letter of classes, but lower case the first letter of variables and methods, by convention.

Comment: The problem is already described in answers below. But I would like to add that if problem is not apparent to you  then use debugger. Any modern IDE provides means of stepping through program and inspect program state. So in your case you see that Ratings are null, you expect them to be set in constructor. Thus run the program in debugger and step into constructor to watch object state changes before and after assignment.

Comment: Etienne and Adam, I think that the "JAVA" spelling persists because the early Java logos were in small caps and many peoploe got it stuck in their head that the language was named, "JAVA." For example: http://rubenerd.com/uploads/logo.java.175.png.

Comment: or perhaps they get too excited sometimes to think of writing codes in Java :)

Comment: @quadelirus: Perhaps you would wish to contribute to [Why do so many people write JAVA instead of Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/why-do-so-many-people-write-java-instead-of-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public Rating (double [] x){
    double [] Ratings = x;
}
```

Here you're declaring a local variable `Ratings` and assigning `x` to it. Right afterwards, the variable goes out of scope.

What you want to do is `Ratings = x;`, which would set the instance variable `Ratings` to `x` instead of creating a new and unused local variable.

Answer (score 6):

Here is your code, nicely formatted and the bug fixed:

```
package com.yourdomain.advisor.score;

public class Rating{

    double[] ratings;
    double sum;
    double rawAdvisor;
    double advisorScore;

    public Rating(final double[] x){
        this.ratings = x;
    }

    public double score(){
        for(int i = 2; i < this.ratings.length; i++){
            this.sum += this.ratings[i];
        }
        this.rawAdvisor = (this.sum - 3 * (this.ratings.length - 2)) / 4;
        this.advisorScore =
            2.5 + 2.5 * (1 - Math.pow(Math.E, -.5 * this.rawAdvisor));
        return this.advisorScore;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.advisorScore);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        final double p1_1[] = { 101, 1, 1, 1.5, .5 };
        final Rating d = new Rating(p1_1);
        d.score();
        d.print();
    }
}
```

You were assigning a value to an unused local variable instead of a field.

And I added a few changes according to java conventions:

- package names are lower case letters
  and periods only and should reflect your domain name
- class names are in TitleCase
- method, field and local variable
  names are in camelCase

See the [Sun Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Also, do yourself a favor: use an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and turn code formatting on

Comment: +1 The return value of score is still just discarded though when called as d.score() in main. Looks like it should really be void

Comment: Yeah i know, didn't  touch that. One option would be to return Rating and make it a fluent interface.

Answer (score 3):

Because your `Ratings` which is member of your class is not initialized just declared so it is currently referring to `NULL`.
and you can't execute method on NULL

in constructor you should use `this.Ratings = x;` which will initilize your member variable which you are trying to use in score method.

I would suggest you to go through [tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem, is that you are defing a new variable name Ratings intead of using the one you already have defined, so Rating is not defined when calling score.

In your constructor, you shouldn't redefine it, just use it.

```
public Rating (double [] x){
    Ratings = x;
        }
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You got two variables with the same name

Change

```
 public Rating (double [] x){
      double [] Ratings = x;
 }
```

to

```
public Rating (double [] x){
    Ratings = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have :

```
double [] Ratings;
```

What is Ratings? Needs to be initialized or be set some non null value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from trying to reference the `Ratings` **instance variable** defined at the top of the class.  This is never assigned to because within your constructor you are creating a **local variable** `Ratings` and assigning `x` to that.  The local variable is then immediately discarded leaving the `Ratings` instance variable pointing to `null`.

The fix is simple:

```
public Rating (double [] x){
  this.Ratings = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you are assigning the array to a local variable rather than the Ratings field:

```
public Rating (double [] x){
    double [] Ratings = x;
}
```

should be

```
public Rating (double [] x){
    Ratings = x;
 }
```

or even, if you want to be more explicit

```
public Rating (double [] x){
    this.Ratings = x;
}
```

I would also advise capitalising Ratings in this way, as it is against Java conventions which makes it confusing to read; google for more information on the topic of naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor declares a new variable Ratings that hides the instance variable.

Package names should begin with lower case letters.

Variable names should begin with lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think in constructor you meant to initialize the class member public double [] Ratings,but in constructor you are creating another double [] Ratings,which is local to constructor.Change the constructor to

```
public Rating (double [] x){
double [] Ratings = x;
    }
```

It will work